# how to make a image generator in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to make a image generator but the only thing I can find anywhere is a random one, but I need them to be and a specific order.

Here's what I have, but I dont want the images to be in random order:

.h file

```
@interface ViewController :UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;
}

-(IBAction)randomimagebutton;

-(IBAction)randomimagebutton2;

@end
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)randomimagebutton {

int randomimages = rand() % 8;

switch (randomimages) {
    case 0:            
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right wihte.png"];
        break;

    case 1:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right red.png"];
        break;

    case 2:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right pink.png"];
        break;

    case 3:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right light blue.png"];
        break;

    case 4:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right dark blue.png"];
        break;

    case 5:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right light green.png"];
        break;

    case 6:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right dark green.png"];
        break;

    case 7:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right orange.png"];
        break;

    case 8:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye right yellow.png"];
        break;

    default:
        break;

}

}

-(IBAction)randomimagebutton2 {

int randomimages = rand() % 8;

switch (randomimages) {
    case 0:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left white.png"];
        break;

    case 1:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left red.png"];
        break;

    case 2:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left pink.png"];
        break;

    case 3:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left light blue.png"];
        break;

    case 4:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left dark blue.png"];
        break;

    case 5:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left light green.png"];
        break;

    case 6:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left dark green.png"];
        break;

    case 7:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left orange.png"];
        break;

    case 8:
        imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye left yellow.png"];
        break;

    default:
        break;

}

}
```

Comment: also xcode4 is just an IDE and not relevant for this question.

Comment: well do you know how to do it?

Comment: why? as I see it, it is answered. And yes, this is a primitive task. But I am sure, you just copied the code and did not invest any time in learning objective-c.

Comment: well sir its is still not answered and i do learn from what people answer on this, also i do not just copy and paste, I read it over and write it myself.

Comment: it is answered. while not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, instead of using `int randomimages`, use an `NSNumber` that you increment each time you get an image. Make the `NSNumber` a property of the class.

**Update:**

Add the property like this:

```
@interface ViewController :UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;
}

-(IBAction)randomimagebutton;
-(IBAction)randomimagebutton2;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *index;

@end
```

And don't forget `@synthesize` in you .m.

In the .m file, do this:

```
- (IBAction)randomimagebutton {

    index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(([index intValue] + 1) % 8)];

    switch ([index intValue]) {

        ...
```

Comment: how would i change the property class. lol sorry about the new to this.

Comment: ok so in the .m file want would i change there

Comment: I updated my answer again. I think I gave you most of the answer, so see if you can get it from here. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: well ok but im getting some bad receiver error

Comment: .m: Bad receiver type 'char *(*)(const char *, int)'

Comment: index it underlined in red with the error on the second index and the third

Comment: What line is that on? The `@property` line?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *index; no error on this

Comment: did you synthesize index? BTW: A NSUInteger would be sufficient. Also scalar types can be ivars.

Comment: Great!, Thank you all, i got it now !